Is there a hard rule about where to place action beats from a nonspeaking character in the middle of a speaking characters dialogue?
Which of the following is correct?

"Yes," I said. "I'm fine with it." She stared at me silently. "Why don't you take the day and think about it? I mean, neither one of us wants to go home."

or

"Yes," I said. "I'm fine with it."
She stared at me silently.
"Why don't you take the day and think about it? I mean, neither one of us wants to go home."


Can you first say what you mean by 'action beats'?

Whatever you mean by 'action beats', the first suggestion denies and the second exemplifies how paragraphs should be used.

There are two conventions for dialogue that seem to contradict each other in your example:

Whenever the speaker changes, insert a paragraph break:

       "John?" ¶
       "Yes?" ¶
       "Would you like a beer?"


Brief, non-dialogue actions by other characters can be inserted within one character's dialogue without paragraph breaks, if the theme of the pagraph remains consistent:

       "Alright, John, I'll try and explain it to you. Look." I pointed at the beer and John turned his eyes to the bottle of lager. "That's a beer." John rubbed his forehead, then looked back at me. "Do you want one?" ¶
       John shook his head. "No."

In this second example, the first paragraph contains one turn of dialogue of one character interspersed with pauses and descriptions of brief parallel actions of another character. That second character does not take a turn in the dialogue during that first paragraph and the first paragraph is unified by its unchanging topic, the speaker elaborately asking John if he wants a beer. Only when the first character ends his turn of dialogue and John answers, first nonverbally (by shaking his head), then by his utterance ("No."), does that first paragraph end.


In your example, the silence of the second character can be understood to be a turn in the dialogue. She does reply, just not with words. Her silence might as well be rendered with words as something like, "I'm not saying anything to that."
If you think about it this way, it becomes clear that her silent reply should get its own paragraph and your second version is the correct one.

Two different speakers should not have dialog in the same paragraph.
Readers quickly lose track of which character is speaking. A new paragraph helps readers by signaling a change.
Also the 2nd version has more gravitas. The silent stare seems to last longer.
